# Shortening a 4-levels-of-match lean4 proof of the CHSH inequality

Tags: lean4, beginner

In the CHSH game, Alice (Bob) is given the value $x$ ($y$) and needs to pick a value $a$ ($b$) such that $a \oplus b = xy$. The CHSH inequality proves they can win at most 75% of the time with classical strategies if $x$ and $y$ are being chosen at random andthe players can't communicate during the game. (Whereas quantum strategies can win 85% of the time.)

Currently I've just proven the inequality for deterministic strategies, but the proof strikes me as repetitive in a way that can probably be fixed. All I do is just brute force evaluate all 16 possible deterministic strategies. The result is this big tree of "cases" blocks with every leaf just being "trivial" since at that point it's just a basic arithmetic evaluation. Is there a way to say, like, "for each assignment of these four expressions, it will be trivial"?

Here's the current proof:

```
def xor (a b : Bool) : Bool :=
match a with
| false => b
| true => !b

infixl:65 " ⊕ " => xor

def strat_wins_case
  (a b : Bool → Bool)
  (x y : Bool)
  : Bool
  := ((a x) ⊕ (b y)) = (x && y)

def bool_2_nat (b : Bool) : Nat :=
match b with
| false => 0
| true => 1

def win_count (a b : Bool → Bool) : Nat
    := ((bool_2_nat (strat_wins_case a b false false))
    + (bool_2_nat (strat_wins_case a b false true))
    + (bool_2_nat (strat_wins_case a b true false))
    + (bool_2_nat (strat_wins_case a b true true)))

theorem CHSH_inequality(a b : Bool → Bool) : win_count a b ≤ 3 := by
  unfold win_count
  unfold strat_wins_case
  cases (a false) with
  | false => 
    cases (a true) with
    | false => 
      cases (b false) with
      | false => 
        cases (b true) with
        | false => 
          trivial
        | true =>
          trivial
      | true =>
        cases (b true) with
        | false => 
          trivial
        | true =>
          trivial
    | true =>
      cases (b false) with
      | false => 
        cases (b true) with
        | false => 
          trivial
        | true =>
          trivial
      | true =>
        cases (b true) with
        | false => 
          trivial
        | true =>
          trivial
  | true =>
    cases (a true) with
    | false => 
      cases (b false) with
      | false => 
        cases (b true) with
        | false => 
          trivial
        | true =>
          trivial
      | true =>
        cases (b true) with
        | false => 
          trivial
        | true =>
          trivial
    | true =>
      cases (b false) with
      | false => 
        cases (b true) with
        | false => 
          trivial
        | true =>
          trivial
      | true =>
        cases (b true) with
        | false => 
          trivial
        | true =>
          trivial
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The combinator tactic [`<;>`](https://lean-lang.org/theorem_proving_in_lean4/tactics.html#more-tactics) is useful here since you are doing the same steps in each branch.

```
theorem CHSH_inequality(a b : Bool → Bool) : win_count a b ≤ 3 := by
  unfold win_count
  unfold strat_wins_case
  cases (a false) <;> cases (a true) <;> cases (b false) <;> cases (b true) <;> trivial
```

Comment: Could you link to the documentation on `<;>`? It's not very searchable.

Comment: @CraigGidney Done (sort of).

Answer (score 3):

Everything here is finite, so you can invoke the decidability checker, `decide`:

```
import Mathlib.Data.Fintype.Pi

infixl:65 " ⊕ " => xor

def strat_wins_case
    (a b : Bool → Bool)
    (x y : Bool) :
    Bool :=
  ((a x) ⊕ (b y)) = (x && y)

def bool_2_nat : Bool → Nat
  | false => 0
  | true => 1

def win_count (a b : Bool → Bool) : Nat :=
  ((bool_2_nat (strat_wins_case a b false false))
    + (bool_2_nat (strat_wins_case a b false true))
    + (bool_2_nat (strat_wins_case a b true false))
    + (bool_2_nat (strat_wins_case a b true true)))

theorem CHSH_inequality (a b : Bool → Bool) : win_count a b ≤ 3 := by
  revert a b
  decide
```

I deleted `xor` since it was already defined in a prerequisite to the imports I am using, but you can reintroduce it under a different name if you need your own definition.

Comment: By the way, you can also define `win_count` more quickly as the size of the "winning set": `def win_count (a b : Bool → Bool) := (Finset.univ.filter (fun p : Bool × Bool => strat_wins_case a b p.1 p.2)).card`.  You don't need `bool_2_nat` for that.  (You do need a few imports, I'll let you figure out which.)